# Run commands and wait for completion in c#

Tags: c#

I need to do this in my c# program.

```
           Process process = LaunchCommandWindow("Special args and environment set")
           process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cmd1");
           process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cmd2");

           //Parse logs
            using (Streamreader sr =  new ())
           { etc etc..}
```

My commands execute correctly, but the problem is that Parse logs code doesnt wait for cmd1 and cmd2 execution to complete. I cannot call exit and  process. waitforexit because, after parsing the logs, I have more commands to execute.

Here is how process start info is set. LaunchCommandWindow()

```
         ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");
        startInfo.Arguments = "/K " + newEnvironmentArgs;

        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        return process;
```

How do I get the parse logs code to wait for cmd2 completion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If "cmd2" writes a completion to the Standard Output stream, you could listen on Standard Output until you see that event, then process from there.

Comment: This would work, though the main thread would enter a busy waiting state while it looks for the completion message.  A new thread would keep the program from going into a 'not responding' state.

Comment: +1 He'll also need to set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true in order to do this.

Comment: @Jeff: Since it appears that sequence is important here, threading should take place at a higher level. This could also be a command-line program, in which case such behavior is probably what's desired.

Comment: @Jeff: That's pretty much true no matter what - however, if this is a console application, and that's its only purpose, that may be desireable.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But this is not an option for me. Only problem with redirecting is that output wouldnt be visible on the screen and I need that. Is there a way I can redirect and as well display the output? Thanks.

Comment: @user393148: Redirect it, and then just use Console.WriteLine to "rewrite it" yourself, so it looks like your program's output.

Comment: Sorry for getting back on this so late. Between the approach above and launching a new command shell process. I am going with the process.waitforext() and process =  LaunchProcess() again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new thread to run the tasks.

Use a `BackgroundWorker`.

When it finishes, it raises an event (in your main thread) from which you can continue running.

This will prevent your program from hanging, and if there is other work to be done, it can allow you to do it while the other thread runs.

[Here's a tutorial](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

-----Edit-----

After further research, here's a thought for the rest:
You do have to set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true, if you want to read the output.

If you don't *have* to run both commands in the same window, you can call
`process.WaitForExit(int)` 
where the int is the number of milliseconds to wait, then launch a new process (or `process` with new arguments) to fire cmd2.

Comment: -1. I'm not seeing any relation between this and the question at hand.

Comment: Any time he's going to run something like this, there's going to be busy waiting, unless he's put together something that can run a command window and report back it's progress at completion.  That's the lead-in to my 'new thread' response.

Comment: Edited in the rest of my answer.  Sorry for the delay, had to dig through some of my old code for how I'd handled this last time I did it.  Using `WaitForExit` keeps you from having to do a reading loop on the output, and results in slightly more stable (and maintainable) code - you can't get into a race condition where you're reading the output stream while it's being written (if that's still a concern...I'm uncertain if it is)

Answer (score 0):

I think **Process.WaitForExit()** method is just what you need. There is also **Process.HasExited** property.
And for launching use something like that "cmd /C cmd1 & cmd2"